# If $w=f(z)=u+iv$ and $u-v = e^x(\cos y - \sin y)$, find $w$ in terms of $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $$w=f(z)=u+iv$$ and $$u-v = e^x(\cos y - \sin y)$$, find $w$ in terms of $z$, where $z$ denotes the complex variable.

What i tried :- I tried differentiating the second equation partially w.r.t $x$ and $y$ , to somehow calculate $u_x,v_x,u_y,v_y$ but somehow , i need the condition that the function $f(z)$ is analytic to apply Cauchy-Reimann's equation. Is something missing in the problem statement (function being analytic )? Is there a way out  ?

Comment: what if you just take $u=e^x\cos(y)$ and $v=e^x\sin(y)$? So in the end, $f(z)$ will be $e^x\cdot e^{iy}=e^{x+iy}=e^z$

Comment: proper solution is required

Comment: Is z=$f^{-1}(w)$ a proper solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another condition. As given, you have one equation in the two indeterminates $u, v$.

If the function $f$ is assumed to be differentiable, that gives another equation.

Comment: Thanks . that helped .